# Install_app_from_unknown_sources dialog does not show in android 10

Tags: android, apk, android-permissions

I'm new to android. I made an application which part of it downloads files. I want to open downloaded files from my app. But my app does not open `apk` files in some phones with android 10 and shows "There was a problem parsing the package" error.

After googling this error turned out the main problem was that install_app_from_unknown_sources was not allowed for my app. In Android 11 and higher android shows a dialog to user and let user change it in android settings but in Android 10 does not show anything but the parsing error.

this is how I open file:

```
public class DownloadFilesAction {
    public void openFile(String fileName) {
        File file = this.getFileByFileNameInDownloadsDirectory(fileName);
        if (file == null)
            return;
        Context context = MyApplication.getContext();
        Intent intent = createIntentToOpenFile(file);
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager != null && intent != null) {
            try {
                if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    private File getFileByFileNameInDownloadsDirectory(String fileName) {
        File targetFile = null;
        try {
            File downloadsDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            File foundFile = new File(downloadsDirectory, fileName);
            if (foundFile.exists()) {
                targetFile = foundFile;
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
        return targetFile;
    }

    @Nullable
    private Intent createIntentToOpenFile(File file) {
        Context context = MyApplication.getContext();
        Uri fileUri = this.getFilePathUri(file);
        try {
            String mime = context.getContentResolver().getType(fileUri);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, mime);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            return intent;
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Uri getFilePathUri(File file) {
        Context context = MyApplication.getContext();
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    }
}
```

and in manifest file I have this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

How can I make android to show dialog for install_app_from_unknown_sources for my app?